# How do I get something in view did load to only be called once?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

Im trying to make a game for the iPhone that has background music.
So this is how it is laid out:
I have a main menu with music running in the background via AVAudioPlayer (I have made a custom method that gets called every time the view loads).
I have this about button, when you press it it "addSubview:aboutView" s and it does that fine, but then when I press the back button which "addSubview:mainView" s it goes back to the main menu, but plays the same music track, on top of the one thats already playing.
I have tried making a int that ++s every time the viewDidLoad is called thats in an if (someInt > 1){} but that int forgets its value every time, so it still duplicates the music.
Help!
I know this is simple, but I cannot seem to work it out, its just one of those days.

Comment: Sorry if there are dual posts, I could not get it to post properly for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restructure your app.

For example this could be one:

```
App delegate
   |_ App Main View Controller
       |_ AVAudioPlayer
       |_ UINavigationController
            |_ Start screen
            |_ Screen #1
            |_ Screen #2
            |_ etc.
```

Comment: I would use UINavigation Controller, but the issue is it always has to have that title bar at the top. Is there a way to remove that?

Comment: yeah, try reading the `UINavigationController`documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBarHidden

Answer (score 0):

If you `addSubview` you probably instantiating your main view again, that's why it does `viewDidLoad` again. You should build a nice logical view controllers hierarchy first, probably based on UINavigationController, if you have view chains that form branches.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to restructure your app. I'd put the AVAudioPlayer in a singleton wrapper (let's call it *MusicPlayer*). The singleton will make sure no extra instances of AVAudioPlayer will be created. If you want I could post some example code from a project of mine, though it makes use of AVPlayer.